# made them sit up straight vs. made them sit upright

Tags: phrase-usage

Do "sit up straight" and "sit upright" share the same meaning? Are they interchangeable?

> On 8 December, during a regular Tuesday meeting about the spread of the pandemic coronavirus in the United Kingdom, scientists and public health experts saw a diagram that **made them sit up straight**. Kent, in southeastern England, was experiencing a surge in cases, and a phylogenetic tree showing viral sequences from the county looked very strange, says Nick Loman, a microbial genomicist at the University of Birmingham.

> Source: [Science](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/12/mutant-coronavirus-united-kingdom-sets-alarms-its-importance-remains-unclear)

Comment: "sit up straight" is more hair-raising than "sit upright".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Sit up straight*, as well as describing a person's posture, is an idiom meaning *suddenly start to pay particular attention*. Those experts were in a routine meeting when they saw the first evidence of the new variant of Covid-19.

We only use *sit upright* in its literal sense.

Comment: You can just say "make them sit up" or very common, "sit up and take notice".